# Why are my deep learning models giving unreasonably high accuracy on test data?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I'm trying to do sarcasm detection on Twitter data to replicate the results mentioned in this [paper](https://aclanthology.org/2020.wnut-1.2.pdf). Binary classification problem. For that I used a separate set of **unlabeled** tweets to create the embedding matrix using Word2Vec model. Before doing that I preprocessed the **unlabeled** data and removed the rare words as mentioned in the paper. Code is as follows:

```
model = Word2Vec(df_hing_eng['tweet_text'], vector_size=300, window=10, hs=0, negative = 1)
embedding_size = model.wv.vectors.shape[1]
```

Next I fit a tokenizer on this **unlabeled** data:

```
tok = Tokenizer()
tok.fit_on_texts(df_hing_eng['tweet_text'])
vocab_size = len(tok.word_index) + 1
```

Next, I created the embedding matrix as follows:

```
word_vec_dict={}
for word in vocab:
    word_vec_dict[word]=model.wv.get_vector(word)

embed_matrix=np.zeros(shape=(vocab_size,embedding_size))
for word,i in tok.word_index.items():
    embed_vector=word_vec_dict.get(word)
    if embed_vector is not None:  
        embed_matrix[i]=embed_vector
```

Now, I'm using a separate set of **labeled** tweets to be used as training and test data (for the DL models). I used the same preprocessing steps as the `unlabeled` data and removed the same rare words we found in the `unlabeled` data. Now I find the maximum length of all tweets in the **labeled** data.

```
maxi = -1
for row in df_labeled.loc[:,'tweet_text']:
    if len(row)>maxi:
        maxi = len(row)
```

After that I used the tokenizer, that I fit on the **unlabeled** data, to create the word indices for the **labeled** data as follows:

```
encoded_tweets = tok.texts_to_sequences(df_labeled['tweet_text'])
```

Now I padded the **labeled** data to the length of the maximum tweets among the **labeled** data.

```
padded_tweets = pad_sequences(encoded_tweets, maxlen=maxi, padding='post')
```

Finally, I split the **labeled** data into training and test data as follows,

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(padded_tweets, df_labeled['is_sarcastic'], test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
```

**Is there any data leakage anywhere from training to test data or any other problem?** Almost all of my DL models are giving more than 90% accuracy contrary to the original paper which reported a maximum of 75% accuracy. The codes for DL models were written by the authors of the papers. I used the same parameters as they mentioned.

The tokenizer was actually fit on a completely different **unlabeled** data that is absolutely separate from (**labeled**) training and test data.

**Edit**

Further analyses of the datasets reveal the followings:

1. There are huge overlaps between **unlabeled** embedding data and **labeled** data.
2. There are many duplicate rows in both **labeled** and **unlabeled** data.

I shared the code of an LSTM below. These codes originally written by the authors of the paper.

```
#define callbacks
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=4, verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [early_stopping]



 #this one--->LSTM

    lstm_out1 = 150
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim,
              weights=[embed_matrix], input_length=max_tweet_len, trainable=False))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_out1, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=adam,
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.summary()
```

Comment: I fit the tokenizer on the unlabeled embedding data which is completely separate from both training and test data. I generated sequences using that tokenizer on undivided training and test data.

Comment: Yeah right, I was confused for a second. There might be some overlap in both datasets but I won't expect it to cause large jumps in accuracy (15%), I'd say the leak would be negligible. Maybe it's related how you defined the models. It will be more clear if you can add a model.

Comment: I don't see any obvious data leakage issue from the code, but you could make it even safer by splitting the labelled data first and then applying the reprocessing (you can keep the max length first, it doesn't matter). The next suspect would be the data itself: could there be a lot of duplicated tweets in the data, causing the same instances in the training and test set?

Comment: @Frightera Plz check my edit portion

Comment: @Erwan Plz check my edit portion

Comment: So the duplicates are clearly causing data leakage, and this certainly causes the overestimated performance. Are you using the same data as the authors of the paper? If yes, maybe they apply some kind of deduplication that you don't have?

Comment: @Erwan I'm not sure if I'm using the same data as the original authors.Now I removed all duplicate rows. What about the common rrows between labeled and unlabeled data? Are they causing any data leakage?

Comment: This is a good question, I'm not sure myself. Well, strictly speaking the answer is yes: there can be data leakage as soon as some data from the test set is seen by system before. So ideally if it's doable it would be better to avoid this as well, but in practice it's sometimes acceptable.

Comment: @Erwan Are the use of fit_on_texts and texts_to_sequences correct here? Basically fit_on_texts is used on embedding data and texts_to_sequences on both training and test data.